# jQuery gmap limits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to generate a map that shows multiple store locations, perhaps 30-40. Only 10 are displaying. I understand that Google limits that, unless you provide a Google API key. I have one, but when I pass it in, Google complains ("Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application"). The key is valid. Also, the jQuery gmap2 docs say the API key is not required. Is there a way around this limitation?

Thanks,

Comment: gmap2 ? why don't you try using the gmap v3 api ? probably they are just trying to kill the v2, although I don't know well, I started with v3 directly last year

Comment: The gmap2-api has been deprecated for ages and in november this year it will start serving a new version wrapping the V3 api instead which might give you complications. See the top of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference for more info.